# Bootstrap modal with feedback not dismissing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using a BS Modal to show the feedback on a newsletter form.
It uses AJAX and PHP to insert the e-mails on DB and returns the STATUS.

The PHP and the AJAX response are working fine, with validations and everything, BUT, when I call the Modal using the JS to show the feedback, the modal doesn't close anymore, can't be dismissed.

The modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">ENGINE|Sistemas</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="response"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(function()
{
  var form = $('#newsletter-form');
  $(form).submit(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:  $(form).attr('action'),
      data: formData
    })

    // ----------------------------------------
    // Success
    // ----------------------------------------
    .done(function(response)
    {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $('#myModal, #response').replaceWith(response);
      $('#newsletter-email').val('');
    })

    // ----------------------------------------
    // Error
    // ----------------------------------------
    .fail(function(data)
    {
      if (data.responseText !== '')
      {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#myModal, #response').replaceWith(data.responseText);
      }
      else
      {
        alert('Ocorreu um erro! Seu email não foi cadastrado.');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I don't understand why tho modal shows up perfectly with the response, but simply doesn't close anymore...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

do you see error js in console?? if no, try this :

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden', function(){
   $("#myModal").remove();
   $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});
```

Comment: I just foundout that the displaying the response is causing the erros. with `$('#myModal').modal('show');` works fine, but if i put the response `$('#myModal, #response').replaceWith(data.responseText);` it stops working!

Comment: And I've already tried to do what you posted, not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now it's working.

I don't know why, but the response was blocking the modal to behave correctly.

Solved just changing:

```
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal, #response').replaceWith(data.responseText);
```

to

```
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#response').text(data.responseText);
```

=)